# In node.js is there a way to reuse a list of const-require statements, in all files?

Tags: node.js, require

In a node project I will have these 20 lines of code ...

```
const db = require('./db')
const comms = require('./comms')
const stuff = require('./stuff')
const blah = require('./blah')
const bleh = require('./bleh')
...
const admin = require('./admin')
```

And I literally paste those 20 lines at the top of each and every one of the 20 .js files in question.

You do this for simple procedural efficiency (any of the lines unused, in that file, VS will harmlessly indicate it's unused, but you never have a missing one, and everyone on the team does the same thing, and you never have to think about it).

{Actually, one team I was on someone wrote a line of script to automate the process! It would just make the top of each file the same, based on all the current files. But setting that solution aside:}

Is there some way to keep those 20 lines in another file `reqs.js` (or `reqs.txt`, or something) and have it "**applied**" to all files?

So it would be something like

```
actuallyRunTheCodeFrom( 'reqs.js' )
```

or something like

```
macro( someMacro )
```

which literally inserts the 20 lines of code in question, "in", this file.

I appreciate I could require reqs.js, and then prepend "reqs." everywhere, that is not what I am asking, thanks.

I believe there is no way to "dynamically const" in node; there's nothing like `['db', 'comms', 'stuff'].foreach(const $0 = require(./$0))`. If I'm wrong, pls tell me.

Anyway to do this?

---

#### The @YoushaAleayoub method!

https://www.mediafire.com/file/t81fppv2x6wnwty/ya.zip/file

it works perfectly BUT unfortunately it does produce a **mass of warnings**

[image]

Also note for the record. With the "y.a. method" you do have to "change the line at the top of each file" each time someone on the team adds or deletes a file.  eg

```
 const { aa, bb, cc } = require('./common.js')
```

becomes

```
 const { aa, bb, cc, dd } = require('./common.js')
```

When a new file is added, they all need to be changed.

(Ideally, I was wondering if there is some sort of "macro like include" - the answer seems to be no.)

Here are the files to copy/paste:

```
ya % ls
aa.js       bb.js       cc.js       common.js
ya % tail -n +1 *js
==> aa.js <==
// aa.js
const { aa, bb, cc } = require('./common.js')

function sayOne() { console.log(1) }
function sayTwo() { console.log(2) }

console.log("test")
console.log("testB")
bb.sayOne()
console.log("testC")
cc.sayOne()

module.exports = { sayOne, sayTwo }
==> bb.js <==
// bb.js
const { aa, bb, cc } = require('./common.js')

function sayOne() { console.log(10) }
function sayTwo() { console.log(20) }

module.exports = { sayOne, sayTwo }

==> cc.js <==
// cc.js
const { aa, bb, cc } = require('./common.js')

function sayOne() { console.log(100) }
function sayTwo() { console.log(200) }

module.exports = { sayOne, sayTwo }

==> common.js <==
// common.js
const aa = require('./aa')
const bb = require('./bb')
const cc = require('./cc')
module.exports = { aa, bb, cc }
```

#### Simple method

https://www.mediafire.com/file/u3f6o1n7jf5pz95/usual.zip/file

If you tediously paste the N "const lines" at the top of every file (i.e. the whole point of this question is to avoid having to do that), as you can see it works fine with no warnings.

To copy/paste:

```
% ls
aa.js   bb.js   cc.js
% tail -n +1 *js              
==> aa.js <==
// aa.js

const aa = require('./aa')
const bb = require('./bb')
const cc = require('./cc')

function sayOne() { console.log(1) }
function sayTwo() { console.log(2) }

console.log("test")
console.log("testB")
bb.sayOne()
console.log("testC")
cc.sayOne()

exports.sayOne = sayOne
exports.sayTwo = sayTwo
==> bb.js <==
// bb.js

const aa = require('./aa')
const bb = require('./bb')
const cc = require('./cc')

function sayOne() { console.log(10) }
function sayTwo() { console.log(20) }

exports.sayOne = sayOne
exports.sayTwo = sayTwo

==> cc.js <==
// cc.js

const aa = require('./aa')
const bb = require('./bb')
const cc = require('./cc')

function sayOne() { console.log(100) }
function sayTwo() { console.log(200) }

exports.sayOne = sayOne
exports.sayTwo = sayTwo
```

As I say, I was basically wondering if there is some sort of "macro like include" in node.js - the answer seems to be no sadly!

Comment: You kinda want to have explicit requires (or imports) in each file that needs things. Modules are cached, so there's no performance impact, but there _is_ clarity when your files explicitly declare what they need. That said, nothing stopping you from creating an object with properties for each require/import and then just exporting _that_ from a single file.

Comment: the downloadable zip file is in the edit to the question since yesterday, notice the link: https://www.mediafire.com/file/t81fppv2x6wnwty/ya.zip/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an aggregator file and then import from there. For example, let's create a collection of files we need imported "everywhere":

first, `a.js` exporting a function

```js
function aFunction() {
  return `a`;
}

module.exports = { aFunction };
```

then, `b.js` exporting a normal const

```js
const B_CONST = `b`;

module.exports = { B_CONST };
```

then, `c.js` exporting a symbol

```js
const cSymbol = Symbol(`c`);

module.exports = { cSymbol };
```

And finally a `d.js` that exports a class

```js
class D {
  constructor() {
    this.d = `d`;
  }
}

module.exports = { D };
```

We can aggregate those in an `imports.js` that re-export them as a single collection:

```
const a = require("./a.js");
const b = require("./b.js");
const c = require("./c.js");
const d = require("./d.js");

module.exports = { a, b, c, d };
```

Which we can now import in any file that needs it. Let's create an `index.js`:

```js
const { a, b, c, d } = require("./imports.js");

console.log(a.aFunction);
console.log(b.B_CONST);
console.log(c.cSymbol);
console.log(d.D);
```

And then let's run that:

```
$node index.js
[Function: aFunction]
b
Symbol(c)
[class D]
```

And if you want to skip the namespace and instead directly export a single specific thing, then just do that, and then have the aggregator export it as part of the collection too.

For instance, let's add an `e.js` that directly exports *just* a function, rather than wrapping it in its own namespace:

```js
function verifyData() {};
module.exports = verifyData;
```

Cool. We simply update our `imports.js`:

```js
...
const verifyData = require("e.js");
module.exports = { a, b, c, d, verifyData };
```

As well as our `index.js`:

```js
const {a, b, c, d, verifyData } = require("./imports.js");
...
console.log(verifyData);
```

And we're done:

```
$node index.js
[Function: aFunction]
b
Symbol(c)
[class D]
[Function: verifyData]
```

Comment: Then I guess we have a barrier to communication that neither of us can overcome. I'll delete most of my comments because clearly they're not useful in helping you edit your post into something that I can understand.

Comment: ?  But you **perfectly helped me** (!), you have explained that in fact, no, **there is no** such macro -like facility in node.js, conversely it's **not** possible to use exactly the same, say, require line at the top to replace the 20 lines in my example.    (sorry if my previous comment was accidentally posted half-way through BTW)

Comment: If that's what you got out of the comments, then great, but that's not what I put into them, and that's not what I intended to say, so that just demonstrates how differently we're both reading the text here =)

Comment: MIscommunications are always a shame, but FWIW rest assured I got a **vast amount** of highest-quality info from the (to me, "extended-discussion" on related topics), and indeed my literal word-for-word precise headline question ("In node.js is there a way to *reuse* a *list* of const-require statements, in *all* files?") has been answered. (Software plumbing is always a hot topic. On the Swift site, every time there's a mechanical question about singletons a massive pro/con singleton war breaks out, ignoring the mechanical question at hand heh!)

Answer (score 2):

If I got it correctly:

Simply create a file named **common.js** where you define your common statements:

```
// common.js file
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
// Add more common statements as needed.
module.exports = { fs, http };
```

Then in your other files, import the **common.js** file:

```
// myapp.js file
const { fs, http, example } = require('./common.js');
// Now you can use fs and http and example in this file.
```

Comment: Node doesn't care. `require("fs")` and `require("./myfile.js")` are the same in terms of the require mechanism.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub it works !!  BUT you get a massive pile of warnings unfortunately.  I've made a test folder, pls see edit to question